# Android BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray get the photo width/height is exchanged than iOS UIImage(data:)

Tags: android, ios, uiimage, bitmapfactory

I get a base64 string from the server, then I parse it to image, on Android side, the image is rotated to 270 degree, its width/height is exchanged than iOS side. Any idea? Thank you. Here is the code:
Android code:

```
val decodedByteArray: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64Str, Base64.DEFAULT)
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedString.size)
Timber.i("image size: ${bitmap.width}, ${bitmap.height}")
```

iOS code:

```
 if let photoData = Data(base64Encoded: base64Str, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters),
    let photo = UIImage(data: photoData) {
        printLog("photo size: \(photo.size)")
        cell.ivPhoto.image = photo
 }
```

Comment: Assuming that both sides received the same image, I would double check the image format (jpg, png, bitmap) on the server and see how it looks on a PC. Update your question with image format and test results.

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for your comment. the base64Str got from the server is same. I suspect if on iOS side and on Android side, they draw bytes to different direction, for example, on iOS, they draw bytes from left to right, but on Android, they draw bytes from top to bottom.

Comment: What is in the base64 sting? So what was base64 encoded? You did not tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your image has a rotation angle in its **EXIF** tag.
The **Bitmapfactory** does not perform any EXIF rotations/transformations at all.

Use the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface) class to get such information. Remember to use the AndroidX variant instead of the deprecated framework one.

If such is the case, then you must rotate the image according to the EXIF angle.
This operation will require to create a new bitmap, therefore in order to avoid a potential [OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError), use some of the tips provided in this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

Answer (score 1):

Check the image base64 data using any base64 to the image viewer. If it's same as uploaded. Then that might the android thing which rotates the image when it converts to base64 to image. So when you convert base64 to image you can rotate the image to a specific angle or portrait.

Answer (score 1):

Android Bitmapfactory does rotate nothing.

Its the used ios code that rotates to original position using orientation information.

For example BitmapFactory does not look at orientation information in a jpg. The image can come in any position and orientation information is needed to put it in right orientation.

So in this case Android/BitmapFactory does not rotate or exchange anything.